# Why my java project is compiling and executing from Maven even though there are some errors I have seen in Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven

I checked out my company project from SVN. I did

```
mvn clean
mvn install
mvn exec:java
```

Every thing is working fine, But I have seen so many errors in eclipse. But no errors in Maven. Why is this happening ?

Comment: You're presumably missing some dependencies. Try `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and re-import the project.

Comment: This sems to indicate that your eclipse project settings and the maven settings are out-of-sync.

Comment: Also try Clean... from the Project menu with Build Automatically under the same menu checked.

Comment: Also, add the eclipse errors, we can only guest if you don't tell us what are the problems.

Comment: Because Eclipse maven integration is terrible.  Eclipse thinks it needs to know about every plugin that you use and if it doesn't it causes issues.  I recommend going Netbeans or IntelliJ for maven projects (which is sad).

Comment: What kind of errors? How did you import the projects in Eclipse? What project meta-data was included with the sources?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your exact errors, it is impossible to answer correctly. The first to try is always

> Maven->Update Project Configuration (from the context menu)

Other options there might also be worth trying.
But, there is something to keep in mind. Eclipse's Maven integration leaves a lot to be desired. It has no native support but instead uses plugins to translate Maven POMs into Eclipse-digestible models. The big downside of this is that for each Maven plugin, Eclipse needs a translator-plugin. So if you use any less-common Maven plugins for which Eclipse has no ready translator, you'll never have Eclipse read you project right. Keep an eye on Eclipse's errors panel to see if it complains about non-supported plugins or such. This is actually the main reason behind me abandoning Eclipse for good. I suggest you try importing the same project into a different IDE, and if it works with no special tinkering, that it's pretty safe to conclude it's Eclipse's fault.
Still, if your problems are related to classes not being resolved, or other such low-level issue, then your project wasn't imported right or is no longer in sync with Maven.

Comment: Pretty off topic here (my comment not your answer :-) ) but what IDE do you use now ?

Comment: I now use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, as my company was nice enough to provide the licence. I'd probably otherwise use the Community edition (or get a personal license during a discount), as it has most of the stuff I need and I couldn't be happier with IDEA. Took about 2 weeks of adaptation but was well worth it. The first benefit you'll see is that your Maven projects are not all red when you open them (just open the main pom) and it can auto-reimport the Maven model on change. If all goes wrong, I guess I'd fallback to NetBeans.